# sql alias to function for reuse in select

Tags: sql

im trying to make the query more efficient, is there a way to use an alias in order to call `regexp_substr` only once?

this is the sql query:

```
SELECT *,
   (SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '(://([a-zA-Z0-9]+):)', 1, 1, 'c'), 4, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '(://([a-zA-Z0-9]+):)', 1, 1, 'c')) - 4)) as custom
FROM table
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: snowflake and redshift

Answer (score 0):

No need for a second `regexp_substr`, simply use 2 argument `SUBSTRING`. (I.e. substring from position 4 to the end):

```
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '(://([a-zA-Z0-9]+):)', 1, 1, 'c'), 4) as custom
FROM table
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/substr.html